# MIPS: load byte instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

Assume that the processor is executing the following instruction:

```
lb $t3,-7($s0)
```

Moreover, assume that the instruction above is located at address `0x004000f0`,
register `$t3` contains value `0x20040144`, and that register `$s0` contains value
`0x305502db`. What value has registers `$t3` after that the instruction has finished executing?

From my calculation:

The format of the instruction is:

```
lb RegDest, Offset(RegSource)
```

we know `$s0` contains value `0x305502db`, which leads to `0x305502db - 7 = 0x305502d4` and this value will be loaded in `$t3`. I am confused here now because the correct answer says `$t3 = unknown`, how come?

Comment: Because it loads from memory at that address and the content of that byte is not given in the problem description.

Comment: @Jester thanks for the comment, how would the problem describe so `$t3` is not unknown?

Comment: By giving the contents of memory at the target address for the load, obviously.   You only know register values, not memory contents other than the 4 bytes containing the instruction word.  Or there would also have a known solution if the text simply told you what value was loaded (and maybe asked you what address it was loaded *from*, or was simply part of a larger question).  Or if the address pointed inside the instruction word.

Answer (score 3):

> `0x305502db - 7 = 0x305502d4`

... so the `lb` instruction will load the byte from the memory (for example: RAM) at address `0x305502d4`, sign-extend it and write it into the register `$t3`.

If the RAM contains the value `0x5A` at address `0x305502d4`, `$t3` will contain the value `0x0000005A`. If it contains the value `0xA5`, `$t3` will contain the value `0xFFFFFFA5`.

> ... the correct answer says `$t3 = unknown`, how come?

Your exercise does not contain any information about the content of the RAM at address `0x305502d4`.

Therefore you cannot say which value `$t3` will contain.